# How do I get checkboxes in all rows of a DataGrid in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, checkbox

I selected and put one checkbox control in datagrid. How can I get checkbox in all rows?

Comment: Are you using WebForms (ASP.NET) or WinForms? And is this a `DataGrid` control, or a `DataGridView`?

Comment: winforms sir,previously  i put checkbox in datagrid from toolvox, but mow im using default property in datagrid.. it ill work for all column sir..

Answer (score 0):

In the databound of the datagrid, you can create a hmtl input control with checkbox type add that control to every row of the datagrid.